# Draw line 90 degrees from line

Tags: ios, core-graphics

On an iOs device I have drawn a line between a `startPoint` and a `endPoint`. After drawing that line I want to proceed drawing with 90 degrees from the `endPoint`. So I have to create a Point on the Screen which I don't know, because the line could be in any angular.

All was programmed using the `CGContextAddLineToPoint`.

What is the right direction to look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the points you know A and B, and the one you don't C.

Then the vector from A to B is:

```
vec.x = B.x - A.x;
vec.y = B.y - A.y;
```

To rotate a 2d vector by 90 degrees, switch the components and negate one. So you could create:

```
rightVec.x = vec.y;
rightVex.y = -vec.x;
```

And then position C at :

```
C = B + t*rightVec;
```

For some non-zero t.

Answer (score 1):

To draw a line that is perpendicular to the line `startPoint` -> `endPoint`, the line needs to start at `endPoint`, and go to the point defined by:

```
X = endPoint.X + (startPoint.Y - endPoint.Y)
Y = endPoint.Y + (endPoint.X - startPoint.X)
```

The line will then be the same length as the original line, but 90 degrees to it, starting at the end of the initial line.